# NPE from kafka streams joins after migrating to named internal topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams app with a topology that include kstream and ktable joins. These joins have been working for years using the default named internal topics e.g. `<app_consumer_id>-KTABLE-FK-JOIN-SUBSCRIPTION-XXXXXXXX`. We recently attempted to migrate to manually named internal streams topics by naming them in the source code, then using the [Kafka Streams Application Reset Tool](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html), passing in the necessary source/input topics. The migration seems like it was successful, but ever since the migration we are occasionally running into this stacktrace leading to crashes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde$SubscriptionWrapperSerializer.serialize(SubscriptionWrapperSerde.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde$SubscriptionWrapperSerializer.serialize(SubscriptionWrapperSerde.java:52) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:59) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:50) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:27) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawValue(StateSerdes.java:192) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.put(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:262) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl$KeyValueStoreReadWriteDecorator.put(ProcessorContextImpl.java:487) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionStoreReceiveProcessorSupplier$1.process(SubscriptionStoreReceiveProcessorSupplier.java:101) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionStoreReceiveProcessorSupplier$1.process(SubscriptionStoreReceiveProcessorSupplier.java:56) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:118) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:432) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:474) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:536) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:792) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:698) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:671) ~[kafka-streams-5.4.2-ccs.jar!/:na]
```

This stacktrace seems very similar to [this reported issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10515). We are running this app distributed *and* our kafka cluster distributed. We are using Confluent Platform (not cloud) 5.4.2 ([based on Kafka 2.4](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html)) for both the cluster (broker, zookeeper, etc.) and for the client packages in the streams app. A few questions: 1. What's the root cause of the issue? 2. Should we expect this issue to be resolved if we upgrade to Kafka 2.7+ (looks like that's where that bugfix linked above is included)? 3. Is there anything we can do to resolve the issue aside from upgrading Kafka versions to 2.7+?

Comment: You dont necessarily need to upgrade the broker. You can update the client dependency separately

Comment: Thanks - updating the client packages alone fixed the issue.